# R:Count daily number of a variable distinguish per ID

Tags: r, count

I've asked the similar question before ([here is the link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31313275/rcount-the-daily-number-of-a-variable-distinguish-per-id)), this time, I also want to calculate the number of v **distinguish** *per day* and *per ID*, but now the "distinguish" not only means that the different `v` for one day, but also means that the different `v` for this day and the forwards days.

For example, if there is a `v1` in the second day, but also in the day before, we don't count the v1 for the second day.

***ID1:***

day1: v1/v2 -----> 2 for day1

day2: v1/v3 -----> 1 for day2

day3: v3    -----> 0 for day3

***ID2***

day1: v4    -----> 1 for day1

day2: v5/v4/v1 -----> 2 for day2

day3: v3/v4   -----> 1 for day3

Here is my data:

```
ID         Day             v
ID1         1              v1
ID1         1              v1
ID1         1              v2
ID1         2              v1
ID1         2              v3
ID1         3              v3
ID1         3              v3
ID1         3              v3
ID2         1              v4
ID2         2              v5
ID2         2              v5
ID2         2              v4
ID2         2              v1
ID2         3              v3
ID2         3              v4
```

With my data above, I wanna get the result like:

```
ID         Day             v         daily_v_distinguish_ID
ID1         1              v1            2
ID1         1              v1            NA
ID1         1              v2            NA
ID1         2              v1            1
ID1         2              v3            NA
ID1         3              v3            0
ID1         3              v3            NA
ID1         3              v3            NA
ID2         1              v4            1
ID2         2              v5            2
ID2         2              v5            NA
ID2         2              v4            NA
ID2         2              v1            NA
ID2         3              v3            1
ID2         3              v4            NA
```

If we use the `setDT(df1)[,  daily_v_ID := c(uniqueN(v), rep(NA, .N-1)), by = .(ID, Day)]`, we have not compared the `v` in this day with the forwards days.

Comment: @ akrun We don't do comparison between different IDs. For ID2, we count `v1` for the 2nd day even `v1`happens in the 1st day for ID1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We could use `data.table` to create the 'daily_v_distinguish_ID'.  Convert the 'data.frame' to 'data.table'  (`setDT(df1)`), grouped by 'ID' we create a logical index based on elements in 'v' that are not `duplicated`.  In the next step, we group by 'ID' and 'Day' column, get the `sum` of 'indx' and concatenate with 'NA' to fill the rest of the elements in each group and assign (`:=` that as 'daily_v_distinguish_ID'.

```
 library(data.table)
 setDT(df1)[, indx:=!duplicated(v) ,.(ID)
    ][, daily_v_distinguish_ID:= c(sum(indx),rep(NA, .N-1)) , .(ID, Day)
    ][,indx:=NULL]
df1
#     ID Day  v daily_v_distinguish_ID
# 1: ID1   1 v1                      2
# 2: ID1   1 v1                     NA
# 3: ID1   1 v2                     NA
# 4: ID1   2 v1                      1
# 5: ID1   2 v3                     NA
# 6: ID1   3 v3                      0
# 7: ID1   3 v3                     NA
# 8: ID1   3 v3                     NA
# 9: ID2   1 v4                      1
#10: ID2   2 v5                      2
#11: ID2   2 v5                     NA
#12: ID2   2 v4                     NA
#13: ID2   2 v1                     NA
#14: ID2   3 v3                      1
#15: ID2   3 v4                     NA
```

A similar option using `dplyr` is

```
library(dplyr)
df1 %>% 
   group_by(ID) %>%
   mutate(ind=!duplicated(v)) %>%
   group_by(Day, add=TRUE)%>% 
   mutate(daily_v_distinguish_ID=c(sum(ind), rep(NA, n()-1))) %>% 
   select(-ind)
```

Or using `ave` from `base R`

```
with(df1, ave(!duplicated(df1[-2]), ID, Day, FUN=function(x) 
                  c(sum(x), rep(NA, length(x)-1))))
#[1]  2 NA NA  1 NA  0 NA NA  1  2 NA NA NA  1 NA
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(ID = c("ID1", "ID1", "ID1", "ID1", "ID1", "ID1", 
"ID1", "ID1", "ID2", "ID2", "ID2", "ID2", "ID2", "ID2", "ID2"
), Day = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
3L, 3L), v = c("v1", "v1", "v2", "v1", "v3", "v3", "v3", "v3", 
"v4", "v5", "v5", "v4", "v1", "v3", "v4")), .Names = c("ID", 
"Day", "v"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -15L))
```